# QGIS crash while delete duplicate geometry

Tags: qgis, geometry, algorithm

I have a polygon shape with nearly 60 000 features (at around 3 000 square kilometres) in QGIS 2.12. I try to delete duplicate geometries from this layer and the algorithm runs until 99%. Then QGIS crashes (this also happens when I use version 2.8).

Any suggestions why this happens? Because of the mass of features? Computer capacity? Something else I have to think of?

Comment: Usually QGIS _looks_ like it crashed (with the "Not responding" message) but more often than not, it is actually still processing the data. You can check this in the **Task Manager** where if you go to qgis-bin.exe, you can see if there's CPU resources allocated to it. Perhaps leave it running for a good few minutes? :)

Comment: I know sometimes it just needs time to process the data, but it's really not working. I left it running for hours, but it didn't work. There is not only the "Not responding" message, but also the "QGIS doesn't work anymore" message and QGIS shuts down. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When dealing with large datasets, you could run a python script outside QGIS; import your layer to PostGIS and write a function; or you could use the GRASS tool **v.clean** with the _rmdupl_ option. Not sure if you're familiar with any of these methods :)

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I will ask someone in this office, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you already guessed, your computer capacity and the large amount of features. You van solve this in Postgis though, if you know how that works.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Unfortunately I don't know much about working with Postgis, but maybe I should give it a try, because I get many answers that include using Postgis. ;)

Comment: Do you have an idea of what the maximum of features is that QGIS can handle with this algorithm? I tried running with a third of the former number of features, but it crashed as well. So do you know where the limit is?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime crashes like this are caused by errors in the data, especially shapefiles. If you want to try something, create a new shapefile and make all the polygons marginally (0.000001) larger or smaller by using the VECTOR BUFFER tool. Then try to run your analysis.

Also, a Spatialite database is the middle ground between the full capability of Postgis. It should give a bit more capacity for QGIS to work on a large dataset like your. It might be worth looking at.